# Firebase getDownloadUrl does not register in Firestore[React.js]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app which allows a person to post the project with its name description and image. I have got the latter to work fine but facing some issues in image part.

I have gotten it to work such that it retrieves the image url and adds it to the firestore only it doesn't and leaves the field blank. But when i re-click the submit button it adds another collection with the link. I thought it must be some network related issue so i even delayed it by a few seconds but to no avail. Here's my code:

```
  const uploadImage = async(e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault()

   

    const image = String(imageUpload.name)
    const imageName = `images/${imageUpload.name}`
    if (imageUpload == null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imageName )
    uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then(()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
     getDownloadURL(ref(storage, imageName) )
        .then((url)=>{
        
          setDownloadUrl(url)
          console.log(downloadUrl)
        }).catch((error)=>{
          alert("not added :(")
        })
  
  
        const createDoc = async() =>{
          await addDoc(projectsCollectionRef, {name: name, description: description, image: downloadUrl})
        }
    
        createDoc()
  
        
      },6000)
      alert( 
        "added"
      )
    })
```

P.S: I am new in React so please pardon my poor writing practice